# C++ Function Pointers In Co-dependent Classes

Tags: c++, function, gcc, function-pointers

I have to classes, `A` and `B`. There are actually many other classes that all share a pointer to `A`, because `A` is sort of a manager that controls all the other classes during runtime.

The idea is that `A` and `B` both open a bunch of file I/Os during their lifetime, but any class can request the execution to stop. At this point, I'd like to gracefully close all the files which are open. `B` and all other classes all contain a member function like

```
void B::CloseFile()
```

So my idea was that I first instantiate `A` which contains an empty vector of `CloseFile` function pointers, then instantiate all the subsequent classes that "register" their own `Close` functions in `A`'s vector. Then any class can call a stop, and call `A`'s (since all classes have a pointer to `A`) `CloseAll` function, which traverses the vector and closes everything its got.

I tried to prototype this in a simple example and I'm getting stuck. Here is the code that doesn't work, the last line throws an error.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;

class B;
typedef void (B::*bfnptr)();

class A {
public:
    // Some methods
    void SetBfn(bfnptr new_ptr) { do_b_ = new_ptr; };
    // Some vars
    int a_ = 0;
    bfnptr do_b_ = nullptr;
};

class B {
public:
    // More methods
    void ZeroMe() { b_ = 0; };
    void SetA(A* obj_a) { aptr_ = obj_a; };
    void IncMe(int op) { b_ += op; };
    // More vars
    A* aptr_ = nullptr;
    int b_ = 1;
};

int main()
{
    // Two instances
    A obj_a;
    B obj_b;

    // Setup B to point to A
    obj_b.SetA(&obj_a);

    // Manipulate A through B
    cout << "A var initially: " << obj_a.a_ << "\n";
    obj_b.aptr_->a_ = 10;
    cout << "A var is now: " << obj_a.a_ << "\n";

    // Object b can do things
    cout << "B var initially: " << obj_b.b_ << "\n";
    obj_b.IncMe(1);
    cout << "B var is now: " << obj_b.b_ << "\n";

    // Set A to point to a function in B
    obj_a.SetBfn(&obj_b::ZeroMe);
}
```

When I compile this with C++14, I get the error

```
 In function 'int main()':
51:19: error: 'obj_b' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
```

This is actually not my question; I'm not sure why this is happening. The actual question I wanted to ask was how to handle the circular dependency between classes `A` and `B`. But why is that error happening?

Comment: `obj_b` isn't a class. It's a variable. You want the class here. Use `&B::ZeroMe`.

Comment: Remember that `A` will need access to a `B` instance to safely call that function though. `this` has to come from somewhere.

Comment: I realize now I could just create `vector<B*>` and the call `CloseFile` from each element. But I am still a bit curious about function pointers academically. I now also get that since `ZeroMe` is not a static function, I need the complete `B` instance. In that case, is it correct that function pointers is not really useful here?

Comment: Previous comment pointless. You've figured out everything I was going to say. Yes, once you store `B*`s, the function pointer is useless. You just have to remember to define the `A` method that's calling the `B` method after `B` has been declared. `void  A::do_stuff_to_B() { for (B *b: Bvec) { b->ZeroMe(); } }` will `ZeroMe` all of the known `B`s.

Comment: Note that function pointers point at functions and methods are not functions (though they might be implemented as functions with extra arguments "under the hood").  You need method pointers if you want to point at methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was hoping to learn a new tool but I guess I can just keep on with what I got. Do you have an example (I guess aside from very low-level code, IRQs etc) where function pointers are the ideal solution to a problem?

Comment: I still find them useful from time to time. A good example is a parser where I could have a `std::map<std::string, bool(X::*)(istream &in)> keyfunc;` so I can do stuff like `keyfunc[token](input);` instead of a big-ass `switch/case` or `if/else if` chain  Here's some good reading on the topic: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Comment: I've gotten lost. What's the actual question? There's probably a duplicate somewhere, but I don't know what to search for.